# How do you run all the project tests in one go in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have all my tests in `/test` in a ruby project and I need a way to run them all with one command. I came up with this:

```
task :default => [:test]

task :test do
  ruby "test/test_1.rb"
  ruby "test/test_2.rb"
end
```

Which if fine but it runs every single test one at a time rather than showing the overall number of failed vs passed tests.

For the record I am using the native testing ruby framework (eg. `Test::Unit::TestCase`)

Anyone can help me improve this poor state of affairs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would do:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
   t.libs = ["lib"]
   t.warning = true
   t.verbose = true
   t.test_files = FileList['test/**/test_*.rb']
end
```